# Getting this error when i run "npm start" command, anyone help me to solve this error

Tags: node.js, package.json, npm-start, npm-package

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path D:\DEMO/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\DEMO\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\desktop\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-09-01T16_04_40_610Z-debug-0.log

I have reinstalled nodejs but still getting this same error when i run "npm start" command

Comment: Well, does `D:\DEMO\package.json` exist?

Comment: Did you run `npm start` in the right directory? Do you have a `package.json` in the demo?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.